# How to play multiple ogg or mp3 at the same time..?

Tags: android, media-player, soundpool, ogg, audiotrack

I'm trying to play 20 ogg files at the same time using MediaPlayer.
This is because I want to make a mixing effect. 
While one music is playing, other files also have to be played.
Actually, I already made an application with this function by iOS, and it didn't have any problems to play and mix.
And now, I should convert this app into android app.
so I sentenced 20 mediaplayer variables

`MediaPlayer player1;
MediaPlayer player2;
MediaPlayer player3;
.....`

```
play1   = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
play2   = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
play3   = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
......

play1.setOnClickListener(this);
play2.setOnClickListener(this);
play3.setOnClickListener(this);
......
```

and whenever I click each button, it play each sound and mix.

```
player1 = MediaPlayer.create(TestActivity.this, R.raw.md_cricket2);
player1.setLooping(true);
player1.start();
......
```

However, I have some problems at this point.
Two sounds mixing is ok, but when I tried to play more than 3 sounds,
some noises like "tick, tick" are added. It sounds like white noise..
I don't know why...
I thought it is really simple to make this mixing application in android, because 
I already did it in iOS, but I don't know what the problem is...
Is there anybody who can advise me?
I think soundpool is not an answer. It is only for short sounds.
MediaPlayer is not proper to play multiple sounds at the same time?
Then, How can I make this function?

Answer (score 1):

Playing sounds simultaneously with multiple media players is not recommend (crashes may occur).
You'd better use [soundpool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html). Unfortunately,  I don't have any experience with it myself so I can't help you there, but perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3039078/741249) will help

Comment: Thanks. I solved this problem using AudioTrack. It works well.