# Is it possible to play two audios simultaneously in one media player in android..?

Tags: java, android

Im developing an app where i want to play two mp3 files simultaneously one as background music and add another mp3 in the middle of the background music.

Comment: You can, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866927/how-to-play-multiple-ogg-or-mp3-at-the-same-time Used AudioTrack, maybe look into that.

Comment: In this link multiple media players were created,but i want to play in one media player.

Comment: I think you have to use multiple mediaplayers. But that shouldn't be a problem, we live in a object oriented world :D

Comment: How can i track Audio streaming from a specified duration of Stream (0-to-Stream Duration).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible using `java.lang.Thread`!

You can start multiple songs by using different threads.